# Trouble with linking

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm trying to write some C++ code for Windows 7 which will connect to a mobile broadband network. When I run the first example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677092(v=VS.85).aspx I get the following when compiling within Visual Studio:

> testII.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_MbnInterfaceManager
>   testII.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IMbnInterfaceManager

or when I compile with the "cl" command at the command prompt I get:

> test.cpp
>   Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> /out:test.exe
>   test.obj
>   test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_MbnInterfaceManager referenced in function _main
>   test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _IID_IMbnInterfaceManager referenced in function _main
>   test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

It would seem I need to link so some library somewhere, can anyone tell me which library and how to link it? Do these errors have anything to do with the mbnapi.idl requirement?

Thanks a lot, appreciate it

Comment: Which libraries are you currently linking to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is include mbnapi_uuid.lib

Comment: @Als .lib files aren't usually headers

Comment: @Als he mean that you need to include the lib file in your linker libraries linking settings list.